# How to declare an instance of a class inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

This is my user.js function. How do I create an instance of it in another file? I understand that this structure is a function that contains a class that contains functions inside it.

**user.js**

```
'use strict';
const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize');
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');

//This is a function that contains a class that contains functions

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
     static init(sequelize) {
        super.init(
        {
          name: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        {
          sequelize,
        });
        this.addHook('beforeSave', async (user) => {
          return user.id = uuid();
        });
        return this;
      }
      static associate(models) {
        // define association here
        User.hasMany(UserRole,
          {
            foreignKey: {
              field:'UserId',
              allowNull: false,
            },
          });
      }
  }

  User.init({
    Id: DataTypes.UUID,
    Name: DataTypes.STRING,
    UserName: DataTypes.STRING,
    Email: DataTypes.STRING,
    Password: DataTypes.STRING,
    PhoneNumber: DataTypes.STRING,
    MobileNumber: DataTypes.STRING,
    DateOfBirth: DataTypes.DATE,
    LockoutEnabled: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    LockoutEnd: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });

  return User;
};
```

In another file I have tried:

```
const {Sequelize, DataTypes} = require('sequelize');
const {sequelize} = require('../../database/connect');
const {userModel} = require('../../models/user');


function GetAll(UserName, Email){
  var option = new userModel;
  var option2 = new userModel(sequelize, DataTypes);
  return "1";
}
```

But both give me this error:

> TypeError: userModel is not a constructor
> at Object.GetAll (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\data\userdata\userdata.js:8:16)
> at GetAll (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\areas\directory\controllers\usercontroller.js:6:27)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> at Function.process_params (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:341:12)
> at next (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
> at Function.handle (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)

### Edit 1

If I remove new from them, I get the error: userModel is not a function.

### Edit 2

Based on the recommendation by Luka Cerruti, I have changed my user.js like this:

```
module.exports.UserModel
```

And in the other file,

```
function GetAll(UserName, Email){
  console.log(UserModel);
  const user = UserModel(sequelize, DataTypes);
  console.log(user);
  return "1";
}
```

But a new error appeared:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'define')
> at Function.init (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:663:53)
> at Function.init (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\models\user.js:17:15)
> at module.exports.UserModel (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\models\user.js:41:8)
> at Object.GetAll (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\data\userdata\userdata.js:8:16)
> at GetAll (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\areas\directory\controllers\usercontroller.js:6:27)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>
> ```
> at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at C:\Users\userone\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> ```

Comment: You need to implement user.js as a module. Read up about [JavaScript module systems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Comment: Hi @kevintechie , isn't user.js already a module? Its already being exported at the top? Sorry Im new to this.

Comment: Hi @traktor , there is no static userModel method. I wanted to call a function called findAll that is available within the User class.

Comment: The arrow function exported by `user.js` doesn't seem to have a `userModel` property.  Where do you call the exported function that returns the `User` class?

Comment: I call it in another file. This usermodel was generated by the sequelize-cli so I'm not too sure about why it was done like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
"use strict";

const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../db.conn');
const Model = Sequelize.Model;
const UserProfile = require('./userProfile.model');
const InterviewSchedule = require('./interviewSchedule.model');

class User extends Model { }

User.init({
    // Model attributes are defined here
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    mobile_num: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
}, {
    indexes: [
        {
            fields: ['mobile_num']
        }
    ],
    // Other model options go here
    sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
    tableName: 'users', // We need to choose the model name
    paranoid: true, //soft deletion.
    timestamps: true, // this will add created_at and updated_at fields in current table, and sequelize will update its values respectively.
});

//associations
User.hasMany(InterviewSchedule, {foreignKey: 'userId', sourceKey: 'id'});
User.hasOne(UserProfile, {foreignKey: 'userId', sourceKey: 'id'});

User.sync()
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`users table synced...`);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

// the defined model is the class itself
console.log(User === sequelize.models.User); // true

module.exports = User;
```

This is the working code from my project. You can then call it by requiring it in other file like `const UserModel = require('../database/models/user.model');`

and query it like `let userData = await UserModel.findOne({ where: { mobile_num: user.mobile_num } });`

Comment: This looks great! Did you manually write it or was it generated by the sequelize-cli?

Comment: here is the official docs for your reference. 

http://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html


please accept the answer, if this helped you.....Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

On user.js

```
// instead of
module.exports = 'bla bla bla'

// try
module.exports.userModel = 'bla bla bla'
```

on other files

```
const { userModel } = require('../../models/user');

// then use new userModel() to interact
```

or you can also let user.js just like it is right now and import it on other files like `const userModel = require('../../models/user');` (without destructuring as it's default export)

For more information, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40295288/18312347

*Even if this works, I would personally recommend using import/export syntax... read more about it on https://javascript.info/import-export*

Comment: I tried changing to .userModel as you said and declared a new userModel(). However, it still said that its not a constructor.

Comment: Would you mind doing a `console.log(userModel)` and see what's getting imported (if something is being imported in first place)?

Comment: It says [Function (anonymous)]

Comment: Ok, please try this syntaxis to initalize the model: `const user = userModel(sequelize)`, without `new`! seems that's how you properly initalize a sequelize object, as you're exporting a function, not the class

Comment: Now theres an error saying that Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'UUID') in the user.js file. Its strange though. It seems like the DataTypes.UUID is not being recognized?

Comment: I added userModel(sequelize, DataTypes) in now and an even weirder error appeared. I have added it to my question.

Comment: I would personally try to import dataTypes where you're importing sequelize (top of user.js files, `const {Sequelize, DataTypes} = require('sequelize');`). Then remove dataTypes from parameters of the function you're exporting, just like `module.exports = (sequelize)`. This might work but I won't say is the ideal way to do it. Sequelize docs are so bad tho >:(

Comment: I tried remove the Datatypes from the parameters and its better but I still get the same error as above

Comment: I think at this stage I'm going to just manually create my user.js and migrations instead of using the sequelize-cli

Comment: Found this answer that might help about this last error you're getting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53931279/18312347. Also you might like to change your user.js using `module.exports` and importing without those `{ }` (I'm not sure if the fact that using `module.exports.userModel` affects how sequelize works as it's not default exporting the module, give it a try if you have not found a solution yet). And yes, for real don't use sequelize-cli. If it's a personal project, I would even suggest another ORM (I'm big fan of typeORM notation and simplicity) just for one reason: documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you won't like to change your `user.js` file

```
const {Sequelize, DataTypes} = require('sequelize');
const {sequelize} = require('../../database/connect');
const getUserModel = require('../../models/user');


function GetAll(UserName, Email){
  var UserModel = getUserModel(sequelize, DataTypes); // this function return User model in user.js file
  var option2 = new UserModel();
  return "1";
}
```

If you can change your `user.js` file then you can export `User` model instead of arrow function and add static setter function to set `sequelize`, `DataTypes`, etc.

Comment: I tried this and it still says that its not a constructor